# System.NullReferenceException when binding WPFToolkit chart

Tags: mvvm, wpftoolkit

WPFToolkit thrown the exception as soon as my property on the viewmodel contains data but not when it's empty!

VIEW:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ChartView"
    xmlns:DV="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:DVC="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
<Grid>
    <DVC:Chart>
        <DVC:Chart.Series>
            <DVC:ScatterSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
                               DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"
                               IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" />
        </DVC:Chart.Series>
    </DVC:Chart>
</Grid>
```

VIEWMODEL:

```
public class ChartViewModel  
{
    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, int>> Data { get; set; }

    public ChartViewModel()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();

        //If I uncomment this, the error is thrown upon binding
        //Data.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 10));
    }
}
```

The top of the stack trace is:

```
at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.ScatterSeries.UpdateDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) in C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\DataVisualization\Charting\Series\ScatterSeries.cs:line 179
at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeriesWithAxes.OnDataPointActualIndependentValueChanged(DataPoint dataPoint, Object oldValue, Object newValue) in C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\DataVisualization\Charting\Series\DataPointSeriesWithAxes.cs:line 257
at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointSeries.OnDataPointActualIndependentValueChanged(Object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs`1 args) in C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\DataVisualization\Charting\Series\DataPointSeries.cs:line 1322
at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint.OnActualIndependentValuePropertyChanged(Object oldValue, Object newValue) in C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\DataVisualization\Charting\DataPoint\DataPoint.cs:line 657
at System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint.OnActualIndependentValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) in C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\DataVisualization\Charting\DataPoint\DataPoint.cs:line 629
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was very far fetched. In my App.xaml.cs I changed language for the sake of localization (I wanted comma as decimal point) by doing:

```
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Globalization;


var window = new MainWindowView();
window.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
window.Show();
```

Obviously, WPFToolkit does not like this.